# How to merge array by taking values from other array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this

```
$array1 = ['name'=>'john', 'age'=> 10]
$array2 = ['name' => 'johnKaff', 'class' => 'User', 'option'=array('c1', 'c2')]
```

The result i want is

```
$array2 = ['name' => 'john', 'class' => 'User', 'option'=array('c1', 'c2'), 'age'=> 10]
```

The values from `$array1` should always override if have same key in `$array2`

Comment: Have you tried [`array_merge`](http://us1.php.net/array_merge)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/array_replace):

```
$result = array_replace($array2, $array1);
```

Where:

- `$array1` - The array in which elements are replaced.
- `$array2` - The array from which elements will be extracted.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => john
    [class] => User
    [option] => Array
        (
            [0] => c1
            [1] => c2
        )

    [age] => 10
)
```

Comment: whats the diff between this and array_merge

Comment: `array_replace()` replaces the values of the first array with the same values from all the following arrays. `array_merge()` merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one and returns the resulting array.

Comment: @user3147180: Basically, `array_replace()` does a **replace** whereas `array_merge()` **merges** second array at the end of the first.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`+` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
$combined_array = $array1 + $array2;
```

The array listed first wins when each array has an element with the same key.

Example:

```
$array1 = array('name'=>'john', 'age'=> 10);
$array2 = array('name' => 'johnKaff', 'class' => 'User', 'option'=>array('c1', 'c2'));
$combined_array = $array1 + $array2;
var_dump($combined_array);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
      string(4) "john"
    ["age"]=>
      int(10)
    ["class"]=>
      string(4) "User"
    ["option"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
          string(2) "c1"
        [1]=>
          string(2) "c2"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [array_merge](http://es.php.net/array_merge):

```
array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: same keys in second associative array will overwrite previous. Use arguments in reverse order: `array_merge($array2, $array1);`